# How to find and select specific div with javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to write js which should work like this. When user clisk on **collapse-all**, find all **collapse** classes and give them **in** class. So the results should be **collapse** class plus **in** class. And then do the same process in reverse. On click on **collapse-all** remove all **in** classes and just leave collapse class.

The structure is following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpi3f92v366to4p/img.jpg

It's about collapsing all sections in twitter bootsrap.

**!UPDATED!**
Here is browser generated code with your proposals:

```
<div class="collapse-all">[<a href="#">alles auklappen / einklappen</a>]</div>
<div class="background">
<div class="collapse-list">
   <div class="content-container style999 collapse-group">
      <a class="mehr-pfeil" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
      <h2></h2>
      <div class="collapse in">
         <p></p>
         <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
         <p></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-container style999 collapse-group">
      <a class="mehr-pfeil" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
      <h2></h2>
      <p class="collapse in"></p>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.row .mehr-pfeil').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var $this = $(this);
          var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
          $collapse.collapse('toggle');
      });


      $(".mehr-pfeil").click(function () {

          if (!$(this).hasClass("mehr-pfeil")) {
              $(this).addClass("mehr-pfeil-active");
          }
          else {
              $(this).addClass("mehr-pfeil");
          }
      });

      $('.collapse-all').on('click', function (e) {
         $('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
      });
   </script>
</div>
```

I have also tried to prevent action of adding **in** class before user has clicked on link:

```
$('.collapse-all').on('click', function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
});
```

**UPDATED**

For those who will have same problem, here is solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.collapse-all > a', function () {
        var $collapseList = $(this).closest('#main-content').find('.collapse-list'),
            $container = $collapseList.find('.collapse').removeAttr('style');

        if ($container.filter('.in').length > 0) {
            $container.removeClass('in');
        } else {
            $container.addClass('in');
        }
    });
    $(function () {
        $('.collapse-all > a').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: start in the jQuery API , there is a suite of class manipulation methods **with examples** http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: Yes, I have already tried but I can not find a solution. Unfortunately.

Comment: Well the way this site works is you should be providing code that shows your attempts, along with some samples of html not just in an image. Effort shown on your part will produce helpful responses

Comment: Ok, thank you for insight. I will take care in future. In morning I will have access to my office computer and then I will paste my code.

Comment: @Ninjakornjaca - did jquery toggle not work for you  ?

Comment: your updated code may work but it is doing lot of things which can be easily done in toggle class

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('.collapse-all').click(function(){
    $('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
});
```

Comment: That isn't terrible, but if one element of that class gets 'in' toggled independently, it will remain out of sync with the rest forever, which is not what the user would want.

Comment: I've tried like that but on start he gave (in) class to .collapse. How to remove that (in) class and then afterwards give (in) class when user clisk on link?

Comment: @Malvolio, that's certainly true. To fix that, I guess you'd have to store the state on the collapse-all element (wether it should do a collapse of all elements or not), in a data attribute for example

Comment: @Ninjakornjaca, so you want all elements to be invisible at the start, even if they have the .in class present in the markup?  You should then just do this in the document ready event:  $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

Comment: Yes, I want to have on start only .collapse class and then afterwards when user clicks, all elements with .collapse class get (in). I hope that your code will work. Thanks!

Comment: @HaukurHaf -- I am not a big fan of data-attributes where [they aren't needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767897/how-to-find-and-select-specific-div-with-javascript-jquery/24769766#24769766)

Comment: @HaukurHaf Hi, i've tried your code but as I said it won't work because on the start i am getting already written "in" classes. Btw. I have tried to add $('.collapse').removeClass('in'); but still the same thing happens.

Comment: @Ninjakornjaca - make sure you do it in the document ready event.  It will work unless something else is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own answer to address an objection I had to HaukurHaf's otherwise fine solution (that it was possible for the elements to become permanently out of sync):

```
$('.collapse-all').click(function(){
        var show = false;
        return function() {
           show = !show;
           $('.collapse').toggleClass('in', show);
        };
  }()
});
```

This would establish a scope that was attached to the function itself, and puts a variable called `show` in that scope to keep the current (intended) state of the elements;

Comment: In what scenario this may occur ?

Comment: @hitesh -- you mean, how might they get out of sync?  Somebody in an another part of the company writes a function to open or close a particular section.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with [jQuery-Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.collapse-all').on('click', function (e) {
         $('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
      });

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/bx397bf8/7/)